# A limit point of a metric space only if there exists a sequence converging to it

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on this problem:

Let (V, d) be a metric space and A $\subset$ V. Proof that a $\in$ V is a limit point of A if and only if there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in N}$ in A such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} = a$.

What I am struggling with is to "construct" this sequence and formulate the proof in a nice way.

So given a is a limit point of A, I know that for any given $\epsilon$ > 0, $B(a; \epsilon) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. So for any positive integer r > 0 I can find a $x_r$ for which $d(x_r, a) < \frac{1}{r}$. Now this is where I get stuck writing the proof. I know that I should be able to associate a sequence with this converging to a, but I cannot get it on the paper.

For the other way around I would say, since we know there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in N}$ converging to a, for any given $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a $M \in N$ such that n > M implies $d(x_n, a) < \epsilon$. I don't know how to finish this part of the proof.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part: You need the axiom of choice here (well, dependent choice). Like you said you can find for each $r > 0$ some $x_r \in B(a, r) \cap A \setminus \{a \}$ - the open ball around $a$ with radius $r$. The axiom of dependent choice now allows you to fix a sequence $(x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N \colon x_n \in B(a, \frac{1}{n}) \cap A \setminus \{ a \}$. It's now easy to see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = a$.

On the other hand, if we have a sequence $(x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ of points $x_n \in A$ converging to $a$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $N$ such that $x_N \in B(a,\epsilon) \cap A$. Hence every $\epsilon$-ball around $a$ contains a point in $A \setminus \{a \}$ - verifying that $a$ is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: @velutluna That's the requirement for being a limit point of $A$: Any neighborhood around $a$ has to include a point in $A$ different from $a$.

Comment: @velutluna Uhm, now that you mention it: We should require the sequence to be in $A \setminus \{a\}$ - yes. I implicitly assumed that this was what OP meant.

Comment: OK. I found my mistake now. Thank you!

Comment: A quick question: If there is an isolated point $a$, do we say the sequence $\{a,a,a,\cdots,\}$ converges to $a$?

Comment: @velutluna Yes, but these sequences are not allowed to validate that something is a limit point of $A$. (Otherwise every point in $A$ would trivially be a limit point thereof - which would render the whole definition pointless.)